# how can i get the screen height (pixel) without status bar & actionbar?

Tags: android, window, screen

how can i get the screen height (pixel) without status bar & actionbar Or It will also helpfull if any body tell how get the heights of statusbar and action bar.I already find the screen height but it including statusbar & action bar. I use support library v7 for action bar.I search online but these solution not work for me.

Comment: Use DisplayMetrics class for getting for width and height.

Comment: i already use this class & able to find the entire screen height including statusbar & action bar. please let me known how get the height of screen display without statusbar &action bar.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get statusbar height you can like that:

```
 Rect rectangle = new Rect();
 Window window = activity.getWindow();
 window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
 int statusBarTop = rectangle.top;
 int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
 int statusbarHeight = Math.abs(statusBarTop - contentViewTop);
```

and what about action bar, in *actionbarsherlock* there is constant values for that: **abs__action_bar_default_height**. Maybe you should try to find something like that in support lib action bar

p.s. Anyway, since you know status bar height, you can get actionbar height by subtraction of activity's main layout screen X value and status bar height value. It will be looks like this:

```
 mMainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Rect rectangle = new Rect();
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
            int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
            int contentViewTop = window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
            int statusbarHeight = Math.abs(statusBarHeight - contentViewTop);

            int[] location = {0,0};
            mMainLayout.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            int actionbarheight = Math.abs(location[0] -statusBarHeight);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, actionbarheight + "", 1).show();
        }
    });
```

this was written "on a fly", just to give you an idea how to do that.

Comment: I use support library v7 appcompat for showing action bar.thanks for reply

Comment: is here "contentViewTop" the total height of statusbar & action bar?

Comment: no, contentViewTop is the top of the activity screen (with action bar, but without status bar)

Comment: ActionBar has method getHeight which you can use ;)